# GLIBCXX_3.4.15, GLIBC_2.15 and GLIBC_2.14 not found - Centos 6.5

Tags: glibc, centos6

I am trying to run an app but I get

```
...
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: VERSION 'GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
/lib64/libc.so.6: VERSION 'GLIBC_2.15' not found
/lib64/libc.so.6: VERSION 'GLIBC_2.14' not found
...
```

When I do "strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC" i get a normal list...

```
...
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
...
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_2.2.5
GLIBCXX_2.3.2
...
```

I don't seem to find a simple tutorial on how to install the missing libs/files/dependencies, (or Centos 6.5 or anything else for that mater).

Can someone explain how to install whatever might be missing on Centos?

Comment: if you cant install/upgrade that version, get centos box from docker and run inside.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain how to install whatever might be missing on Centos?

You need `glibc >= 2.15` and `libstdc++ >= 3.4.15`.

In *theory*, installing e.g. `glibc-2.19` on the system should work (glibc provides backward binary compatibility), but [this message](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=43944#p186912) suggests that you would not find a standard package for your OS with such an upgrade.

Instead you would have to either install a second version of glibc, as [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host), and redirect your application to use that version by binary-patching the loader encoded into the application, or run your application in a chroot (where you can install any version of glibc you like).

Similar considerations apply to `libstdc++.so.6` as well, except you don't have to install it into the fixed location -- you can install newer copy anywhere, and point `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to it.

Your final (and most likely easiest) alternative is to build the app you are trying to run from source, or obtain a pre-built binary for your distribution (one that doesn't require newer libraries than what you have).