# Install GLIBCXX_3.4.15 on Centos 6.9

Tags: server, centos6, glibc, libs, garrys-mod

I have a problem when I try to start my server Garry's Mod. Here is the error I get

```
Failed to open dedicated_srv.so (/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by bin/dedicated_srv.so))
Add "-debug" to the ./srcds_run command line to generate a debug.log to help with solving this problem
Sun May 13 01:17:52 CEST 2018: Server restart in 10 seconds
```

strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH.
```

There you have a way to have glibcxx_ 3.4.15 on CentOS 6.9, Because I really need CentOS 6 to run other applications ?.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are dozens of existing questions on StackOverflow explaining this. You need a newer version of `libstdc++.so` than the one that comes with CentOS 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GLIBCXX\_3.4.15, GLIBC\_2.15 and GLIBC\_2.14 not found - Centos 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662807/glibcxx-3-4-15-glibc-2-15-and-glibc-2-14-not-found-centos-6-5)

Answer (score 1):

Just try to install file `libstdc++-4.8.5-28.el7.i686.rpm`

```
yum install http://centos.biz.net.id/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libstdc++-4.8.5-28.el7.i686.rpm
```

.

```
[root@linux ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
[root@linux ~]# strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
[root@linux ~]#
```

Comment: Link broken, I edit here for a fix. Seems like they change it all the time so if it doesn't work simply search for it at http://centos.biz.net.id/7/os/x86_64/Packages/